# Указанный домен не существует или не доступен

Tags: c#, active-directory

Если я запускаю программу от доменной учетной записи, то все работает отлично. Если я запускаю от локальной записи то на строке **checkEntry.Name.ToString();** возникает исключение Указанный домен не существует или не доступен.

```
DirectoryEntry checkEntry = new  DirectoryEntry("LDAP://MyDomain.com/dc=MyDomain,dc=com", @"MyDomain\MyUser", "MyPassword", AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
checkEntry.Name.ToString();
```

Аналогичный вопрос на [http://stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32600610/the-specified-domain-does-not-exist-or-could-not-be-contacted)

Answer (score 1):

При использовании **AuthenticationTypes.Secure** аутентификация, возможно, происходит не по логину и паролю:

> Доменные службы Active Directory при проверке подлинности клиента
>   используют протокол Kerberos и, возможно, NTLM. Если вместо имени
>   пользователя и пароля указана пустая ссылка (Nothing в Visual Basic),
>   то ADSI выполняет привязку к объекту, используя контекст безопасности
>   вызывающего потока, т. е. либо контекст безопасности учетной записи
>   пользователя, под которой запущено приложение, либо контекст
>   безопасности учетной записи пользователя клиентского компьютера,
>   олицетворяемого вызывающим потоком.

Если требуется аутентификация по логину/паролю, то можно воспользоваться конструктором без указания типа аутентификации.

Comment: Выдает ошибку "сервер неработоспособен". Странное поведение...